# Cast as decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, decimal, variable-length

I have 4 value in a column. For example;

```
ColumnA
2.651
3.5
4.55
7.9
```

And I want to sum it all and cast as a decimal;

```
 select CAST(sum(ColumnA) as Decimal(LEN(sum(ColumnA)),2)) FROM tablename;
```

however I am getting this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server dbrank-tsql, Line 7

Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

When I just run select len(sum(columnA)) which is 5 and type it to;

```
 select CAST(sum(ColumnA) as Decimal(5,2)) FROM tablename;
```

it is working. But I cannot always first find the length of this number and then type it to cast.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is your `SELECT`? `decimal` doesn't allow for an expression for it's precision or scale, it **must** be a literal. You also have more left parathesis (`(`) than right parenthesis (`)`).

Comment: okay maybe I should type it this way       select CAST(sum(ColumnA) as Decimal(LEN(sum(ColumnA)),2) FROM tablename;

Comment: No, that won't work, again, the precision and scale *must* be a literal. `LEN(sum(ColumnA))` isn't a literal.

Comment: And I also add right parethesis same problem again

Comment: ... I've told you specifically about one of the problem twice... You will continue to get the error because you haven't addressed all the problems. To repeat myself again again: a data type (in this case `decimal`) **cannot** have its length, precision or scale defined by an expression. It ***MUST*** be a ***LITERAL***. For example: `10`, `18`, `2`, or `19`. `LEN(sum(ColumnA))` is an expression and is **NOT** a valid literal value.

Comment: Why do you want the value's precision value to vary anyway? That doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Actually I wanted to round this number (sum(ColumnA)) but it always has a lot of zeroes. To remove these zeroes I use "cast as decimal". And when I just run this --> select len(sum(columnA)) from tablename; it returns 5, And I thought maybe I can use it this way. I dont know if there is any other way.

Comment: Round this number to *what*? `5` doesn't have a lot of zeroes, it doesn't have any...

Comment: for example -- > select round(sum(columnA),2) from tablename; returns 18,600. But I dont want to zeroes. I just want to 18,6. 5 means length of this number.

Comment: So instead of `18600` you just want `186`? The precision properly of a `decimal` won't change that. Also the value `18600` in a `decimal(5,2)` would error; it's too large (the largest value you can store in a `decimal(5,2)` is `999.99`).

Comment: @Larnu 18,600 means 18.600 in some other locale :) OP is apparently confused by numbers value and presentation - he wants to strip trailing zeroes from decimal part. This is not task for SQL anyway.

Comment: In your presentation layer, you set how `decimal` will be displayed. If you *really* have to do this in SQL, you can do `FORMAT(value, '0.#####')`